# Porting mailbox code from Python 2 to Python 3 - problem with mbx.add()

Tags: python-3.x, email, mbox

I have a simple E-Mail filtering program that has been working satisfactorily in Python 2 for many years and I'm trying to convert it to Python 3.  It runs OK in Python 3 as long as there aren't 'extended' (i.e. non-ASCII) characters in the message but if there are my call to mbx.add() fails with this error:-

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chris/.mutt/bin/filter.py", line 102, in <module>
    mailLib.deliverMboxMsg(dest, msg, log)
  File "/home/chris/.mutt/bin/mailLib.py", line 52, in deliverMboxMsg
    mbx.add(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/mailbox.py", line 603, in add
    self._toc[self._next_key] = self._append_message(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/mailbox.py", line 758, in _append_message
    offsets = self._install_message(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/mailbox.py", line 830, in _install_message
    self._dump_message(message, self._file, self._mangle_from_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/mailbox.py", line 215, in _dump_message
    gen.flatten(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/generator.py", line 116, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/generator.py", line 181, in _write
    self._dispatch(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/generator.py", line 214, in _dispatch
    meth(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/generator.py", line 432, in _handle_text
    super(BytesGenerator,self)._handle_text(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/generator.py", line 249, in _handle_text
    self._write_lines(payload)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/generator.py", line 155, in _write_lines
    self.write(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/generator.py", line 406, in write
    self._fp.write(s.encode('ascii', 'surrogateescape'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 30-32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The main program simply reads the incoming message from standard input (via .forward) and makes it into a message with:-

```
msg = mailbox.mboxMessage(sys.stdin.read())
```

Then it's delivered to a local mbox file with:-

```
mbx.add(msg)
```

where `mbx` is an instance of `mailbox.mbox`

So what should I be doing to get this to work in Python 3, do I need an explicit encode and decode somewhere or what?